# Accessing other controls by name in a Silverlight ControlTemplate

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, controltemplate

I have a custom control that inherits from `ContentControl`. Inside the generic.xaml file is a simple Grid with 2 rows:

- Row 1 - A toggle button
- Row 2 - A `StackPanel` with a `TextBlock`, named *"Stackpanel1"*

The `ToggleButton` has its own nested `ControlTemplate` which has `VisualState`s for Checked/Unchecked.

Is it possible to reference "Stackpanel1" from inside the `ToggleButton`'s control template somehow? In order to show or hide the stackpanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: no.

You'll need to do this with a bit of code in the CustomControl that monitors the `IsChecked` state of this `ToggleButton` part that sets a visual state for the custom control so that a `VisualStateManager` on the Custom control itself.